# Como solucionar error de instalación 0x80072F8F en descargar paquete de idiomas en windows 10

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows10

Amigos estoy tratando de instalar sql server 2014 express en mi equipo, el problema que tengo es que me genera este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según se necesita instalar el paquete de idioma de español España, bien al tratar de instalar el paquete me produce este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El windows que descargue viene con español mexicano, alguien me podría decir como puedo solucionar este error, ademas si trato de instalar el sql server 2017 me presenta un mensaje y al darle en aceptar se cierra el programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar en aceptar me genera ce cierra el programa de instalación, como puedo agregar un paquete de idiomas de manera Offline, le agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

Tienes que cambiar la configuración regional y de idioma. Esta opción esta en Panel de Control -> Configuración Regional y de Idioma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]